# Specify different validation groups for each item of a collection in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

[[Documentation about collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)] When embedding forms (collection type) is possible to specify validation groups for each item, based on the current item? It seems not working ATM.

The `TaskType` form adding a collection of tags:

```php
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Form/Type/TaskType.php

// ...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array(
        // ...
        'by_reference' => false,
    ));
}
```

For example we have two tags (tag 1 and tag 2) and a new tag is added using the "Add" button (via JavaScript):

```
-----------
| add tag |
-----------
- tag 1 (existing)
- tag 2 (added clicking the "add tag" button)
```

Tag 1 should be validated against `Default`, `Edit` groups while tag 2 against `Default` group only.

### `TagType` form defining dynamic validation groups

Based on the underlying data, if tag is new it gets `Default` group, if exists `Default`, `Create` groups:

```php
// ...

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $tag = $form->getData();

            $groups = array('Default');
            if (null !== $tag && null !== $tag->getId()) {
                $groups[] = 'Edit';
            }

            return $groups;
        }
    ));
}

// ...
```

### `Tag` entity with a constraint in the "Edit" group

An example with `Tag` defining two properties (accessors omitted):

```php
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Edit"})
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     */
    protected $description;

    // ...
}
```

For an **existing tag**: description should not be blank. For a **new tag**: description can be blank.

### Proof form is valid, validator shows errors (wrong!)

Just edit an existing tag and leave the description blank. The **form validates** but the **validator service shows errors**:

```php
$form = $this->createForm('task', $task)
    ->handleRequest($request);

$validator = $this->get('validator');

if ($form->isValid()) {
    foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
        // Validate against Default, Edit groups
        $errors = $validator->validate($tag, array('Default', 'Edit'));

        if (null !== $tag && null !== $tag->getId()) {
            echo 'Existing tag #'.$tag->getId();
        } else {
            echo 'New tag';
        }

        echo ', errors: '.count($errors).'<br>';
    }

    die('Form is valid.')

    // ...
}
```

Output:

```
Existing tag #863, errors: 1
Form is valid.
```

**Update 1**: I've tried (without success) with a static method `determineValidationGroups` as suggested [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data):

```php
public static function determineValidationGroups(FormInterface $form)
{
    $groups =  array('Default');
    if ($form->getData() !== null && null !== $form->getData()->getId())
    {
        $groups =  array('Edit');
    }

    var_dump($groups);

    return $groups;
}
```

In `TagType` form:

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // ... 
        'validation_groups' => array(
            'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Tag',
            'determineValidationGroups'
        ),
    ));
}
```

Output with just one existing tag and one created using the "add tag" link seems correct. But no errors for the existing tag leaving the description blank:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Edit' (length=4)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Edit' (length=4)

rray (size=1)
  0 => string 'Default' (length=7)

rray (size=1)
  0 => string 'Default' (length=7)
```

Comment: please show code where you set validation group for your entities

Comment: Edited my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 12):

*The complete code I used to test my answer is on https://github.com/guilro/SymfonyTests/tree/SO21276662.*

`Valid` constraint force Validator to validate embed object, and AFAIK the API provides no way to set validation group.

But at a higher level, we can ask Form component to cascade ValidationListener to all embed forms, and use the Form component API to set validation group.

We must use :

- `'cascade_validation' => true` option in the FormBuilder, at all levels. It is set to `false` by default.
- a callback in TagType settings to set validation group. (You were on the right track.)
- `'error_bubbling' => false`, as it is true by default in collections

and we're done, we can display the form with all errors next to corresponding fields.

in TaskType.php :

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('tags', 'collection', array(
            'type' => 'tag',
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ))
    ;
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
        'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
  }
}
```

in TagType.php :

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description', 'text', array('required' => false));
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Tag',
        'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
            if ($form->getData() !== null && null !== $form->getData()->getId())
            {
                return array('Edit');
            }
            return array('Default');
        },
        'error_bubbling' => false,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why we (Symfony developpers) all know and use the `Valid` constraint to validate embed objects, when it makes much more sense use this `'cascade_validation'` option, which I just discovered. Thanks for asking, I learned a lot myself by answering.

Comment: Great job dude, you finally did it!

Comment: Fist thanks for all your research work! Right now I'm with phone so I'll read your answer tomorrow and we'll see. In the meanwhile I've found another workaround: group sequence providers!

Comment: Yes, I just read it on http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence sounds pretty cool too ! It provides exactly the same functionality than `validation_group` option of FormBuilder : dynamic validation group. I guess your workaround was a bit more complicated, but as a benefit you got it to work with the validator in every scope (including with `Valid`), and not only in form validation. Well done ;)

Maybe I can turn my answer community wiki so you can and the way you did ?

Comment: Also made a PR to symfony-doc to add it on option list of Collection type page. We all lost much time because  `cascade_validation` was only on base Form type page, and not listed as inherited option of Collection.