# Apply specific validation group for each element of a collection in Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, symfony-3.4

I had to upgrade one of my projects from symfony 2.8 to symfony 3.4, and I noticed a huge change in the validation process.

To simplify let's say I have a User entity, with many Addresses entities.
When I create / update my User I want to be able to add / remove / update any number of addresses. So in symfony 2.8 I had this kind of situation

**User**

I use annotation validators

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

//...
class User
{
    //...
    /** 
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, max=10)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $addresses;
    //...
}
```

**UserForm**

```
src/AppBundle/Form/UserForm.php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, [
            'type' => AddressType::class,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ])
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'validation_groups' => // User's logic
    ]);
}
```

**Address**

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/Address.php

//...
class Address
{
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="user")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"zipRequired"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable="true")
     */
    protected $zipCode;
    //...
}
```

**AddressForm**

```
src/AppBundle/Form/AddressForm.php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('zipCode', TextType::class)
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Address::class,
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
            /** @var Address $data */
            $data = $form->getData();
            $validation_groups = [];

            // Simplified here, it's a service call with heavy logic
            if ($data->doesRequireZip()) {
                $validation_groups[] = 'zipRequired';
            }

            return $validation_groups;
        },
    ]);
}
```

**In symfony 2.8**

On 3 addresses added, two have to valid the zipRequired group, one not. I works !

**In symfony 3.4**

I added `@Assert\Valid()` to User::$zipCode declaration and removed the `'cascade_validation' => true` (not in method configureOptions but it seems unused) as it's deprecated.

But now on 3 addresses added, two have should to valid the zipRequired group, and one not : Only User's class validator_groups are used, **so I can valid a form with incoherent data** !

I checked with xdebug and the `validator_groups` callback in `AddressForm` is called but validators are not.

I tested the solutions decribed here : [Specify different validation groups for each item of a collection in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276662/specify-different-validation-groups-for-each-item-of-a-collection-in-symfony-2) but it can't work anymore as in symfony 3.4 `cascade_validation` on a property throws an error

In my situation the logic involved is too heavy to use a solution ad described here [Specify different validation groups for each item of a collection in Symfony 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726823/specify-different-validation-groups-for-each-item-of-a-collection-in-symfony-3) as it is very inneficient to rewrite the whole `validation_groups` callback in individual methods and it apply the groups on all child entities.

***The Behaviour of `@Assert\Valid` and `cascade_validation` are different, is there a way to handle embed form individual entity validation_groups in symfony 3.4 or the feature is definitely gone ?***

Comment: did you have fixed it? I'm at sf 5.1 with the exactly same problem

Comment: just found that they will respect any validation group added on the root form, perhaps the callback at the children form runs and return correct group list, they are someway being override by the validation groups of the root form.

Comment: saddly they called it a feature: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31441 the only way i could find is adding an callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an expected behavior (the entire form should be validated from the root validation_groups, as you can see the explanation here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31441) the only way i could find to solve this problem is using an callback validation inside the collection item (entity):

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/Address.php

//...
class Address
{
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="user")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable="true")
     */
    protected $zipCode;
    //...

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback()
     */
    public function validate(): void {
        if ($data->doesRequireZip()) {
            // validate if $zipCode isn't null
            // other validations ...  
        }
    }
}
```

more about symfony callback assert: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

this solution was made in symfony 5.1, but this probably works from 2.8+

#### Update

just to add my final solution was adding the validation throug the validator, forcing each property against an specific group (also you dont need to force Default if your form already did it).

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback()
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContext $context): void
{
    $validator = $context->getValidator();
    $groups = $this->doesRequireZip() ? ['requiredZipGroup'] : [];
    $violations = $validator->validate($this, null, $groups);

    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationInterface $violation */
    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        $context->buildViolation($violation->getMessage(), $violation->getParameters())
            ->atPath($violation->getPropertyPath())
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

passing `null` to second argument on `$validator->validate()` will force the `Assert\Valid` to run through the object `$this`, so, all constraints and also callbacks within the `$groups` will run

Comment: I didn't have to use this specific solution since a while. But your solution look great.
Anyway, it's still too bad they changed this behaviour.